# integrate the gtk4(from Msys2) library into VS code editor

Tags: user-interface, gtk, vscode-tasks, grpc-c++

i've tried to create a GUI in C++ using gtk4 ,i've already install it but when i try to include <gtk/gtk.h> the compiler say : no such directory;

i hope someone can help me .

I've already modify the json file related to the directory to include it like this,it remains the same.

if someone know any solution,feel free.

i also have another question : includin the library gtk4 from the cmakelist maybe a solution ? if yes,can someone tell what is the name of the headers files?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zENR.png)